# Command Line / Powershell command to pipe file names to an application

Tags: command-line, automation, powershell

I would like to input all the filenames in the current directory after an application name, like so:

```
root\file1.ext
root\file2.ext
root\file3.ext

$ app.exe file1.ext file2.ext file3.ext
```

I could write a batch file that could do this automatically and add it to the PATH variable, which is an okay solution. But can PowerShell for example let me write a command like this on-the-fly?

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
app.exe (dir *.ext)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

`dir *.ext | app.exe $_`

Comment: I don't think this can work. The $_ can only be used in a pipeline context 9i.e. a process block)